# The mcc compiler "Depfun error" when building dll with .NET-dependencies and Enumerations That Encapsulate Data

Tags: matlab, mcc, matlab-compiler

I ran into problems in MATLAB R2010b when creating a DLL that uses .NET-integration and enumerations with encapsulate data.

Example:

1. There is a .NET Assembly which is used in MATLAB, let's call it "MyAssembly" (MyAssembly.dll).
2. There Matlab Enumerations Class "OpenMode"

   ```
   classdef OpenMode
       methods
           function obj = OpenMode(netType)
               obj.Net = netType;
           end
       end
       properties
           Net
       end
       enumeration
           ReadOnly  (MyAssembly.OpenMode.ReadOnly)
           ReadWrite (MyAssembly.OpenMode.ReadWrite)
       end
   end
   ```

   This class uses the .NET enumeration: "MyAssembly.OpenMode"
   In such a way to access the .NET-enumeration via Matlab-enumeration (In my case it is necessary for cast types):

   ```
   netElem = OpenMode.ReadOnly.Net;
   cls = class(netElem)
   cls = 
       MyAssembly.OpenMode
   ```
3. The Matlab-Function, that should be exported:

   ```
   function retVal = MyFunction(inputs)
       NET.addAssembly('MyAssembly.dll');
       flag = OpenMode.ReadOnly;
       netFlag = flag.Net;
       % Some code...
   end
   ```
4. Add .NET Assembly in Matlab (checking)

   ```
   NET.addAssembly('MyAssembly.dll')
   ```
5. Try to compile the Dll:

   ```
   mcc -B csharedlib:MyLib MyFunction
   ```

   ...and get the error:

   ```
   Depfun error: 'Undefined variable "MyAssembly" or class "MyAssembly.OpenMode.ReadOnly".' 
   ??? Error using ==> mcc
   Error executing mcc, return status = 1 (0x1).
   ```

The mcc compiler does not detect in code enumeration that "MyAssembly" exists, but here is a function will be compiled successfully:

```
    function retVal = MyFunction(inputs)
        netflag = MyAssembly.OpenMode.ReadOnly;
        % Some code...
    end
```

If you have faced similar problems in MATLAB and found a solution, please tell me what to do.

Thanks!

Regards,
iroln

Answer (score 2):

I seem to find solutions to these problems. It's not very elegant, but it works.

The mcc compiler has the option "*-a filename*". This option enables you to add the specified files for CTF archive. You want to add all the files that defines the enumeration using .NET Assemblies:

Example for my case:

```
mcc -B csharedlib:MyLib MyFunction -a OpenMode
```

...or in general:

```
mcc -B csharedlib:MyLib MyFunction -a projectdir/*.m
```

I have automated this with a build-script. 
This is so far the only solution that works.